# Sorting array by frequency of elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, frequency

Here is what i have so far

```
int[] numbers = { 3,5,4,3,8,8,5,3,2,1,9,5 };
int[] n = new int[12];
int[] k;

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    n[number]++;
}
Array.Sort(n);
Array.Reverse(n);

foreach (int value in n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

I know i am missing the part where i sort the frequency of the elements after i counted them and i just cant get my head around it. I'd appreciate some help, Thanks!

Comment: what is a k score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the problem with your solution ?

Whereas you correctly keep the frequencies of the numbers in the table called `n` in your code, which hereby I would call it `frequencies`, then you `Sort` this array. This action breaks your solution, since each frequency is associated with the corresponding index of its location in the array.

E.g. If an instance of this array is this [8,2,1,7,6]. When you call the `Sort` method on this array, this would have as a result the array to be sorted and the order of the elements of the array would be this [1,2,7,6,8]. Before calling sort, the first element of the array was indicating that the number 0 (the index of the first element is 0) has been found 8 times in our `numbers`. After sort, the first element is 1, which means now that the frequency of the number 0 is 1, which is apparently wrong.

If you want to keep it your way, then you could try something like this:

```
int[] numbers = {  1,2,2,9,1,2,5,5,5,5,2 };
int[] frequencies = new int[12];
int k = 3;

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    frequencies[number]++;
}

var mostFrequentNumbers = frequencies.Select((frequency, index) => new 
                                            { 
                                                Number = index,
                                                Frequency = frequency
                                            })
                                      .OrderByDescending(item => item.Frequency)
                                      .Select(item => item.Number)
                                      .Take(k);

foreach (int mostFrequentNumber in mostFrequentNumbers)
{
   Console.WriteLine(mostFrequentNumber);
}
```

> Are there any other approaches ?

An easy way to do this is to use a data structure like a Dictionary, in which you would keep as keys the numbers and as the corresponding values the corresponding frequencies.

Then you can order by descending values the above data structure an keep the k most frequent numbers.

```
int[] numbers = { 1,2,2,9,1,2,5,5,5,5,2 };
int k = 3;

Dictionary<int, int> numberFrequencies = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    if(numberFrequencies.ContainsKey(number))
    {
        numberFrequencies[number] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
            numberFrequencies.Add(number, 1);
    }
}


var mostFrequentNumbers = numberFrequencies.OrderByDescending(numberFrequency => numberFrequency.Value)
                                           .Take(k)
                                           .Select(numberFrequency => numberFrequency.Key);


foreach (int mostFrequentNumber in mostFrequentNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mostFrequentNumber);
}
```

You can also achieve the same thing by only using LINQ:

```
int[] numbers = { 1,2,2,9,1,2,5,5,5,5,2 };
int k = 3;

var mostFrequentNumbers = numbers.GroupBy(number => number)
                                 .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Count())
                                 .OrderByDescending(keyValue => keyValue.Value)
                                 .Take(k)
                                 .Select(numberFrequency => numberFrequency.Key);


foreach (int mostFrequentNumber in mostFrequentNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mostFrequentNumber);
}
```

Comment: @Ale You are very welcome. Please read the update, in order you understand what wasn't correct with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Linq extensions:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

private static IEnumerable<int> Solve(int[] numbers, int k) {
    return numbers
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .Take(k);
}
```

Then you can call:

```cs
var numbers = new []{1,2,2,9,1,2,5,5,5,5,2};
var k = 3;
var result = Solve(numbers, k);
foreach (int n in result)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be very terse:

```
var frequents = numbers.GroupBy(t => t)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(t => t.Key)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t)
    .Take(k)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Errm... you haven't used k and I think the OP wants numbers whose count is 1 to be included don't they?

Comment: @RichN yes i forgot to consider `k`, now added.